# Command ESP 07 ESP8266 over Wireless

Tags: esp8266

I need to send commands from an usual laptop to the ESP8266. (Thus no CP2102, just 3.3V Vcc and GND)
How can I do this?

I tried to start a TCP server with the AT+CIPSERVER command, however, the server has to be started every time the module starts.

It's not clear for me how I should set HIGH or LOW for a GPIO pin on ESP8266 module over Wireless.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default firmware for the ESP does not save the TCP  server settings by default. You would need either a microcontroller that will set up the server, or replace the firmware with something like Node.js that can set up the server by itself.

As for toggling the gpio, there are many tutorials online for that. That is too broad a question here.